# How to test CRYPTDB proxy?

Tags: mysql, linux, proxy

I'm trying to test cryptdb

But when I do:

```
mysql -u root -pletmein -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307
```

I get an error like:

> Lost connection to MySQL server at ‘reading authorization packet’, system error: 0

and on proxy I get:

```
170423 10:49:07  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
main/Connect.cc:70 (do_connect): connecting to server 127.0.0.1 user root pwd letmein port 3306
main/Connect.cc:74 (do_connect): mysql_real_connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  cannot connect
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Also, I'm running cryptdb and mysql on the same VM

Comment: There's a lot of info in that last line. `The error means the system cannot find the path specified.` Does the path `/home/admin1/cryptdb-m/cryptdb-master/shadow/` exist?

Comment: actually now what i get is this "170423 10:49:07  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
main/Connect.cc:70 (do_connect): connecting to server 127.0.0.1 user root pwd letmein port 3306
main/Connect.cc:74 (do_connect): mysql_real_connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  cannot connect
Aborted (core dumped)